# Relative Layouts with ad banners

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem I have is that I cannot properly display my GLSurfaceView with two advertising banners. I want to position them at the top and at the bottom of the mobile screen and above the GLSurfaceView (the main game window). How can it be achieved? Below is the current layout xml that I have

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

<ad banner 1
    android:id="@+id/admobView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

<ad banner 2
    android:id="@+id/mmediaView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/gameWindow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For background, most adviews are actually WebViews so you are running two WebViews along with your GLSurfaceView at the same time.

Comment: And what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just that WebView are relatively heavy so there may be issues when its trying to render more than one along with GLSurfaceView. My guess is that the webview is trying to use hardware rendering but your using it so they aren't getting drawn correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got it. For those of you who'll encounter the similar issue in the code above I've changed the android.opengl.GLSurfaceView xml node to RelativeLayout and positioned it before ad banner nodes. Then in the java code I've created GLSurfaceView and added it to the RelativeLayout node through addView method. And it finally works

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem occur before also. One thing you can do is create a `RelativeLayout` dynamically in the `onCreate` method of your Activity. In this layout, you will instantiate the GLSurfaceView as normal, but instead of setting it the view with `setContentView`, you will add it as a view to the layout. You will also add the banners to the view as your please and then set the layout as the view instead of just the GLSurfaceView. Below is what I use to add a banner to the bottom of a view in a game. See if you can adapt it to your needs.

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    int adId = 0x12346;
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "YOUR_AD_ID_NUMBER");
    adView.setId(adId);

    GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams glParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    glParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, adId);
    glParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    layout.addView(glView, glParams);

    setContentView(layout);

    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: In the post above I mention two banners (not one). I had used before the pure java code, but unfortunately one of the banners (Millennial Media) obscure the whole screen with the white rectangular area, that's why I decided I'll try to use xml (as in most MMedia examples).
And as stated above, those two banners need to be shown above the GLSurfaceView - they shouldn't restrict its area